# What is some standard analysis for "Look me in the eye"

Tags: syntax, morphology, cases, morphosyntax, prepositions

I am looking for hints where to find a ("standard") analysis of something like this english dative construction:

```
Look me in the eye
```

Clearly, the "the" in this phrase is semantically scoped BY the me (read: "the" eye of whoever me denotes). So I wonder if this 3sg may somehow have been raised from inside "in"'s scope, where also the "the" sits.

Comment: Googling "possessor raising" should get you started.